# Is "several prizes" a direct object or an indirect object in "There are thought likely to be awarded several prizes."?

Tags: meaning

From [Andrew Radford. (2004). English Syntax: An Introduction. p.155.]

> There are thought likely to be **awarded several prizes**.

I can not figure out the meaning of the sentence because of not being certain whether 'several prizes' is a direct object or an indirect object.

A noun or pronoun should be in the square brackets of "There are thought likely to be [ ].", but the sentence above does not follow this rule.

Comment: Does the author claim that it's a good sentence? _It is thought likely that several prizes will be awarded_ would be much clearer.

Comment: @Kate Bunting He doesn't claim it's a good sentence. But throughout his argument, he keeps using this sentence as an example.

Comment: The sentence makes little sense, but that aside, "several prizes" is undoubtedly the direct object of "awarded", Why would you think it may be an indirect object? Note that in canonical clauses containing just one object, that object is always a direct object.

Comment: Using it as an example of what? "There are thought to be" is grammatical but it is typically followed by a noun phrase, like "bats in the attic".  "several prizes awarded" would be more natural, but "awarded" is marginal. However, **likely** makes the sentence a non-starter for me.

Comment: Having searched Google Books for "there are thought likely", I found that Noam Chomsky originally wrote the sentence to demonstrate some obscure point of linguistics. Nobody would use that sentence in real life.